# How to install specific MySQL version

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have two machines, one local (mine) and one server... both of them have MySQL installed, but for some reason they use different MySQL versions, although the installation process was exactly the same.

When I run `mysql --version` in my machine I see:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

But in my server I see:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Because they are different, I can't restore the dump of one into the other. Would it be possible to specify a version when installing mysql?

Thank you.

Comment: Post this on https://askubuntu.com/ I will reply

Comment: `mysql --version` is only showing the client version. To look at the server version connect and `SELECT VERSION()`

Answer (score 3):

I believe what your looking is how to install an specific version of a package using apt, right?

Here an answer:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package

Another way is installing downloading from mysql website:

> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html
>   Version of your server
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
>   Latest version